# Grails index field order

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

Consider a table containing NAME, DATE, and VALUE, (amongst other things) that I want to index on NAME/DATE/VALUE and NAME/VALUE/DATE.

How do I configure this in Grails?

The following always creates both NAME/DATE/VALUE...

```
name(index:'name_date_value_idx,name_value_date_idx')
date(index:'name_date_value_idx,,name_value_date_idx')
value(index:'name_date_value_idx,name_value_date_idx')
```

The following ignores the first date index meaning name_date_value_idx doesn't contain the date field when created...

```
name(index:'name_date_value_idx,name_value_date_idx')
date(index:'name_date_value_idx')
value(index:'name_date_value_idx,name_value_date_idx')
date(index:'name_value_date_idx')
```

For completeness we're using a PostgreSQL Database. I would hope that this wouldn't matter though.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Sounds like a broken design in Grails indexing, if it doesn't let you specify the field order in indexes. Can you just write the SQL to create the indexes manually?

Comment: Sorry for late response - yes this is what we ended up doing; we just hoped there's be an alternate.